# Is "at the age about" correct usage?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases, quantifiers

This is taken from a composition of a TOEFL student.
[image: composition]

I am wondering whether "at the age about" is correct usage or "at the age of about" is just more idiomatic. I would be grateful for any comments.

[Google Books Ngram Search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20age%20about%2Cat%20the%20age%20of%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20age%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20age%20of%20about%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I don't know if your alternatives are really possible (FWIW, they don't sound very good to me), but I think *at about the age of seven* would be more idiomatic.

Comment: The idiomatic expressing is "about the age of", meaning "around the age of".

Comment: And you know that this essay, good for a TOEFL composition, has more issues than just this, yeah?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang [statement], don't you?

Comment: A TOEFL student is not a good reference for English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I see and hear:

> **at around the age** of seven

much more frequently than

> at the age about seven

or

> at the age of about seven

Both seem weird to me. About is rarely used to describe age; usually around or approximately, in more formal cases.

> at the age around seven

is almost never used, too.

> at the age seven

is incorrect. In all except more formal cases, this is used most frequently:

> for the children when they were around seven

Hope this helps clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example sentence from the Scholastic website:
"**At about the age of** 7, children enter what Piaget termed the concrete operational period, which lasts until they are about 12 years old. "
https://www.scholastic.com/parents/family-life/creativity-and-critical-thinking/development-milestones/cognitive-development-6-7-year-olds.html

Comment: Can you please cite the source?